# Issues with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

I understand the concept of repetition 0 or more times (*) and grouping '()' on there own, but I'm having trouble understanding them given practice examples.

For example, (yes)* contains both the empty set and the word 'yes', but not y or ss. I assume that it doesn't contain those words because of grouping, but would that mean the word 'yesyes' is also valid as the group has been repeated?

In contrast, I assume with the Regular Expression 'yes*', any character can be repeated. For example 'y', 'ye' 'es' 'yes', 'yy'. However the solutions we have been provided with state that the word 'y' isn't contained. I'm confused.

Comment: `yes*` matches `ye` or `yes` or `yesssssss`. Only the `s` gets the modifier.

Comment: if you want to match `y`, `ye`, `es`, `yes`, `yy` ... you have to use a character class: `[yes]+`

Comment: @chris85 You're right...and I've been spending way too much time on SO lately.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of (yes)* is correct ...
(yes)* matches the string "yes" (exactly - no shorter, no longer) 0 or more times - ie the empty string or yes,yesyes, yesyesyesyesyesyes etc

But your understanding of yes* is NOT correct ...
yes* matches the string "ye" followed by 0 or more "s" characters - ie ye,yes,yess,yessssssss

Answer (score 1):

The "zero or more" `*` modifier applies only to the character or group immediately preceding it.

In the first example, we have the group `(yes)*` - this will match `''`, `'yes'`, `'yesyes'`, etc.

In the second example, `yes*`, the modifier applies only to the letter `s`.  It will match `'ye'`, `'yes'`, `'yess'`, etc.

If this is not clear then perhaps you can elaborate a little on the source of your confusion.